# Union-Find Algorithm (Finding Cycle) Without Using Malloc

Tags: c++, malloc, union-find

I've been advised that using malloc in a c++ program shouldn't be done. How can I convert this to a non-malloc code? Thank you!

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/union-find-algorithm-set-2-union-by-rank/

Comment: In C++ you should use `new` operator instead of `malloc`. E.g. `(struct Edge*) malloc( graph->E * sizeof( struct Edge ) ); ` should be `new Edge[graph->E];`.

Comment: Even better would be to use `std::unique_ptr` or other smart pointer, but I think it's better to understand how `new` works at first.

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved my problem. However since I want to have a malloc-free code, how can I also convert this bit of code using new: 

int *parent = (int*) malloc( graph->V * sizeof(int) );

Comment: Since you're allocating space for an `int` you need to have `new int[graph->V]`.

Comment: Ohh I understand now. Thanks so much again :) My code finally worked.

Comment: You're welcome. I converted this to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you should use `new` operator instead of `malloc`. E.g. `(struct Edge*) malloc( graph->E * sizeof( struct Edge ) );` should be `new Edge[graph->E];`. It reduces the boilerplate and makes code less error-prone.

Don't forget to use `delete` or `delete[]` instead of `free`. Otherwise the behaviour is undefined.